# anomalous behaviours of jQuery ajax function's success

Tags: javascript, jquery, iis

I wrote following code :

```
$.ajax({ url: link + "?" + Math.random(), success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
}});
```

Although the alert gives me what `responseText` should give ideally when I use from glassfish. But when I loaded exactly same file in VS, to my horror, I got `[Object]` as the output of alert.
What's wrong?

By the way, what I return is XML not JSON.

Comment: What gives you the idea that this has to do with the success callback instead of `alert` or your own page that gets called?

Comment: Didn't get you .. what can be wrong with an innocent alert??

Comment: Nothing with the `alert` per se -- but rather with its input. But it's not the poor callback's fault.

Comment: agreed. Now I figured that it was 'intelligently' returning the XMLDom parsed object. But still I wonder why it returned text previously when I tried in a jsp page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery will by default perform an "intelligent guess" on your data type and pass the success function the **formatted** response. So if, for example, your url supplies json data the success function will be handed the parsed json object, not just a string. So `alert({...})` will show `[object Object]`

If you want just the textual output, use:

```
$.ajax({
   url: link + "?" + Math.random(),
   success: function (response) { alert(response); },
   dataType: 'text'
});
```

Comment: agreed. Now I figured that it was 'intelligently' returning the XMLDom parsed object. But still I wonder why it returned text previously when I tried in a jsp page?

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that in the second case JSON is being returned you will need to do:

```
$.ajax({ url: link + "?" + Math.random(), success: function (response) {
            $(response).each(function() {
/*do something with data, firefox with firebug allows you to do console.log($this) which will show you the data in a window below the browser, Chrome also has a similar feature, alerting in an iterator is never a good idea.*/
})
}});
```